# Update kendo grid columns without page reload in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, grid, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where user can select list of columns from grid and save the selection by giving name (i.e view name). Each saved selection (view name) will show up as drop-down above grid so that user can change grid columns whenever they want. In current implementation, whenever user selects view name from one drop-down value to other, i call action method to select that view name as current view name. Then **page reloads** to invoke Index' action method to retrieve current view names columns values. I am using visible attribute in grid to show and hide columns in grid.

Now i was wondering if i can update the grid columns without reloading the page when user change the view name from the dropdown.

Thanks
Sanjeev

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Here is my setup:
**ViewModel:**

```
namespace MvcApplicatioin.Models
{
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeColumns EmployeeColumns               { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeViewNames { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeSelectedViewId                   { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeResponse
    {
        public int Id           { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName  { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeColumns
    {
        public bool Id        { get; set; }
        public bool FirstName { get; set; }
        public bool LastName  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var service = new EmployeeService();
            EmployeeViewModel model = new EmployeeViewModel();
            long currentViewId;

            //setup views and column preferences
            EmployeeColumns employeeColumns = service.GetCurrentEmployeeColumnsPreferences();
            model.EmployeeColumns = employeeColumns;
            model.EmployeeViewNames = service.GetAllEmployeeViewNames(out currentViewId);
            model.EmployeeSelectedViewId = currentViewId;

            return View(model);
        }
 }
```

**Razor:**

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Info:";
}

<h3 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Employee Info</h3>

<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" class="btn_Search" />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplicatioin.Models.EmployeeResponse>()
            .Name("GridEmployee")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Width("170px").Visible(Model.EmployeeColumns.Id);
                columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width("190px").Visible(Model.EmployeeColumns.FirstName);
                columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width("170px").Visible(Model.EmployeeColumns.LastName);                
            })
            .ToolBar(tools =>
            {
                tools.Template(@<text>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-7 pull-right" style="padding-right: 0;">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            @Html.Label("Grid View:", new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-xs-4 control-label view" })
                            <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                                @Html.DropDownList("lstEmployeeViewNames", new SelectList(Model.EmployeeViewNames, "Value", "Text", Model.EmployeeSelectedViewId), "- Select View Name -", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto;" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </text>);
            })
            .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }).ButtonCount(4))
            .AutoBind(false)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(10)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("SearchEmployee", "Employee")))
        )
    </div>
</div><!--//row-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSearch').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //This prevent the submit button onclick from submitting by itself

        $('#GridEmployee').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    });

    //Change event for Dropdown placed inside the Grid's Toolbar - To Change the view
    $("#lstEmployeeViewNames").change(function (e) {
        var selectedViewId = $('select#lstEmployeeViewNames option:selected').val();

        if (selectedViewId == null || selectedViewId == '') {
            alert("Please select the view name from the dropdown first !!");
            return;
        }

        $.post("/Employee/SetEmployeeColumnsCurrentPreferences", { viewId: selectedViewId }, function (data) {
            window.top.location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do a search in client. I know it doesn't tell how to show and hide columns, but at least it could put you on the right track.

The trick is to manipulate $("#GridEmployee") instead of posting.

```
function search() {
    var searchCriteria = $("#searchField").val();
    var gridData = $("#GridEmployee").data("kendoGrid");

    if searchCriteria != "") {
        gridData.dataSource.filter({ field: "FirstName", operator: "contains", value: searchCriteria });
    } else {
        gridData.dataSource.filter({});
    }
}
```